# Email header change Received : by

Tags: php, email

I want to change the email header Received: By

I am trying to set it in this function of php mailer class

```
private function ServerHostname() {
    if(!empty($this->Hostname)) {
        $result = 'master.orangebuddies.com';
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {   
        $result = 'master.orangebuddies.com';
    } else {      
        $result = 'master.orangebuddies.com';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Currently my headers are following

> Delivered-To: tahir@codenterprise.com
>   Received: by 10.180.4.197 with SMTP id m5csp44504wim; Wed, 19 Mar 2014 04:43:04 -0700 (PDT)
>   X-Received: by 10.180.20.176 with SMTP id o16mr18965647wie.7.1395229384278; Wed, 19 Mar 2014 04:43:04 -0700 (PDT)

I want to change from `Received: by 10.180.4.197 with SMTP id m5csp44504wim;` to `Received: by tahir.test.com`

Comment: That header is nothing you can add yourself, it's set by the mail transfer program that handles the message delivery. You'll have to configure it differently/teach it its name/change your DNS resolution so it can discover its name.

Comment: Your SMTP server is adding those headers.